# VBA and SurveyMonkey API

Tags: vba, surveymonkey

I have tried to do access the SM API through VBA. I have left out the JSON for now as I am already in trouble. The below is giving me "Developer Inactive" as a result, though I have another project in VB.NET (using a .NET DLL) where the same key and token works fine and I can retrieve the list of surveys.
What am I doing wrong?

```
Public Sub GetSMList()

Dim apiKey As String
Dim Token As String
Dim sm As Object

apiKey = "myKey" 
Token = "myToken"

Set sm = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")

With sm
    .Open "POST", "https://api.surveymonkey.net/v2/surveys/get_survey_list", False
    .setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Bearer " & Token
    .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"

    .send "api_key=" & apiKey

    result = .responseText
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're sending your API key as part of the request body of your POST request. Add the query parameter to the URL directly and this should work.

```
"https://api.surveymonkey.net/v2/surveys/get_survey_list?api_key=" & apiKey
```

You'll then need to use "send" to send a JSON encoded request object. For get_survey_list, an empty object ("{}") will get your started.

Comment: Thanks @Tony. It works! I am now plunging into the JSON world. Confusion is where I am at right now ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of this code is to show error handling. This is vbscript but vbscript is pastable into VBA. The error will probably tell you why.

**ALWAYS DO ERRORS on files (users delete them), networking or internet (they are not guaranteed to work), and registry reads (users delete them)**.

The URL has to be 100% correct. Unlike a browser there is no code to fix urls.

The purpose of my program is to get error details.

How I get a correct URL is to type my url in a browser, navigate, and the correct URL is often in the address bar. The other way is to use Properties of a link etc to get the URL.

Also `Microsoft.XMLHTTP` maps to `Microsoft.XMLHTTP.1.0`. `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Msxml2.XMLHTTP` maps to `Msxml2.XMLHTTP.3.0`. Try a later one

Try this way using xmlhttp. Edit the url's etc. If it seems to work comment out the if / end if to dump info even if seeming to work. It's vbscript but vbscript works in vb6.

```
 On Error Resume Next
 Set File = WScript.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
 File.Open "GET", "http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/default.aspx", False
 'This is IE 8 headers
 File.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0; Trident/4.0; SLCC1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; Media Center PC 5.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30618; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; BCD2000; BCD2000)"
 File.Send
 If err.number <> 0 then 
    line =""
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf & "" 
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf & "Error getting file" 
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf & "==================" 
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf & "" 
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf & "Error " & err.number & "(0x" & hex(err.number) & ") " & err.description 
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf & "Source " & err.source 
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf & "" 
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf & "HTTP Error " & File.Status & " " & File.StatusText
    Line  = Line &  vbcrlf &  File.getAllResponseHeaders
    wscript.echo Line
    Err.clear
    wscript.quit
 End If

On Error Goto 0

 Set BS = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
 BS.type = 1
 BS.open
 BS.Write File.ResponseBody
 BS.SaveToFile "c:\users\test.txt", 2
```

Also see if these other objects work.

```
C:\Users>reg query hkcr /f xmlhttp

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Microsoft.XMLHTTP
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Microsoft.XMLHTTP.1.0
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.3.0
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.4.0
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.5.0
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Msxml2.XMLHTTP
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Msxml2.XMLHTTP.3.0
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Msxml2.XMLHTTP.4.0
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Msxml2.XMLHTTP.5.0
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0

End of search: 12 match(es) found.
```

### Also be aware there is a limit on how many times you can call any particular XMLHTTP object before a lockout occurs. If that happens, and it does when debugging code, just change to a different xmlhttp object

Comment: Thanks @trigger! I will add error code to this project as soon as I have the basics working. Your code seem useful to me when I am there!